# python socket works only locally and on near by laptop

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

I finished working on a 2 player game with python-socket
While I tested it locally on my computer it worked fine,
so I tested the code on my laptop but it didn't work(the client couldn't connect to the host)
when the laptop was the client and for some reason, it did when the laptop was the client.
I tested it with my friend too but both when he was the host and I was- didnt work.

this is the code for the server:

```
    import socket
    import pickle
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    hostName = input('host name(if you are the host write "host"):')
    if hostName == "host":
        host = True
        hostname = socket.gethostname()
        s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(hostname), 4242))
        print(f"your host name is: {socket.gethostbyname(hostname)}")
    
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()

    else:
        host = False
        s.connect((hostName,4242))
```

The error says that the client timeout when it tried to s.connect

Comment: What value are you putting for the hostname in the client side?

Comment: *it didn't work...* What exactly didn't work? Did you get an error message, or a time out, or something else? Please add these details to the question.

Comment: I'm just copy-paste after it prints the hostname,   and send it to myself

Comment: President James k. polk(nice name) I wrote at the end that I get timeout because the client don't connect to the host

Comment: Ok so that will have you the name of the host running the server. Have you got that name in DNS or /etc/hosts etc, how is the client machine meant to convert the hostname to an IP address to make the connection?

Comment: The gethostbyname function gives my ip4 always. this is what I use to connect the host...

Comment: Oops sorry, I missed the `gethostbyname` call. So are both the client and server on the same network? what happens if you try to telnet from the client machine to the host ip and port

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on my laptop and it's working
correctly.
I think it's the firewall

check out this answer:
[python socket Windows 10 connection times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231849/python-socket-windows-10-connection-times-out)

Comment: That fixed the problem I had when my computer was the host and the laptop was the client but when I tried to do this with my friend it didn't work again :/

Comment: Check if your friends firewall is also doing the same on his laptop